# Robocopy One Log logfile for 3 tasks

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm trying to create one log file for all of my three Robocopy Backup tasks. The Problem is how can I create only one Logfile for all 3 tasks.

Thanks

```
robocopy "$env:UserProfile\desktop\" "$Destination\desktop" *.* /copy:DAT /log:C:\Users\user\Desktop\irjgegj\LOG_+$LogTime.log
robocopy "$env:UserProfile\pictures" "$Destination\pictures" *.* /copy:DAT
robocopy "$env:UserProfile\documents\" "$Destination\documents" *.* /copy:DAT
```

Comment: Why not [append](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) into same log file?

Comment: @vonPryz Hi I have edited my code, into my post, I know I should use LOG+ but how would the code look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

/log+:C:\Users\user\Desktop\irjgegj\LOG_+$LogTime.log